# How to insert one image on top of another image in html?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am having two images. I want to insert 2nd image on top of 1st image. 1st image is larger than the 2nd image. So I want my 1st image fully cover the div tag and 2nd image should place in the center of the 1st image. I had tried many css code but didn't get success.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="A.aspx.cs" Inherits="A" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css"> 

        .fishes { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; } .fish { position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 80px; } 

    </style>
   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
         <center> <img src="cropped-longheaderbog1.jpg" class="fishes"/>
          <img src="bannerfans_17362179.png" class="fish"/> </center>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT OF THE CODE :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpWGc.png)

I want to place the upper image in the center. But don't know how to do?

Comment: Please add a starting point in code to your question, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Here is the simplest in my opinion
https://jsfiddle.net/45gtzmho/

```
div {
  width: 1280px;
}


img:first-of-type {
  width: 800px;
}
img:last-of-type {
  margin-left: -600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```